# Form login button enabled after password field has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hello guys I have a login page with two inputs username and password and one button. I want to put a class on that button after password field has first character filled in. How can I do that , Thank's. If is possible to do that only with css will be awesome, or a small script to add a class on that button.

```
<form>
   Username  <input type="text" name="first" id="first" /><br/><br/>
   Password  <input type="text" name="last" id="last" />
    <br/>
</form>

<input class="crbl" type="submit" name="last" id="last" value="login button" />
```

css

```
/*Normal State*/
.crbl{
    margin-top:10px;
   border:1px solid #555555;
    border-radius:5px;
}
/*after password field has one character filled in state*/
.class{
???
}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uGudk/16/

Comment: Why don't you use type="password" instead?

Comment: :) Is just a fiddle example, is not so important that, my problem is to give a class on login button after first character from password input field.

Comment: id should be unique in your document, "last" is there twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toggleClass` and `keyup` methods.

```
// caching the object for avoiding unnecessary DOM traversing. 
var $login = $('.crbl'); 
$('#last').keyup(function(){
   $login.toggleClass('className', this.value.length > 0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5eYN5/

Note that IDs must be *unique*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using javascript. FIrst thing you need to put on password input the following event

```
Password  <input type="text" name="last" id="last" onkeyup="myFunction(this);"/>
```

Then you define the javascript function:

```
function myFunction(element) {
    if (element.value != '') {
         document.getElementById('last').attr('class','password-1');
    } else {
         document.getElementById('last').attr('class','password-0');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**make sure your ID is unique**.. since you have two IDs with the same name in fiddle.. i changed the password id to 'password'...

use `keyup()` to check the key pressed.. and `addClass()` to add the class..

try this

```
$('#password').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val()==''){
    $('#last').removeClass('newclassname'); //if empty remove the class
  }else{
    $('#last').addClass('newclassname');  // not not empty add
  }
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/uGudk/23/)

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/uGudk/19/)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#last').keyup(function(event){
            var password_length =jQuery("#last").val().length;
            if(password_length >= 1){
           jQuery("#last_button").addClass('someclass');
            }
else
{
jQuery("#last_button").removeClass('someclass');
}   
        });   

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to handle the entire input, with the "on()" Jquery method.
Use the very first parent

```
 <form id="former">
   Username  <input type="text" name="first" id="first" /><br/><br/>
   Password  <input type="text" name="last" id="last" />
    <br/>
</form>
<input class="crbl" type="submit" name="last" id="last_btn" value="login button" />
```

Then in Jquery

```
$("#former").on('keydown, keyup, keypress','#last',function(e){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if ( value.length > 0 ) {
        $("#last_btn").addClass('class'):
    }else{
        $("#last_btn").removeClass('class');
    }
});
```

With "on" method you can handle many event of the input as you can see...

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#YourTextBoxId').keyup(function (e) {
                if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
                    $(this).toggleClass("YourNewClassName");
                }
                else if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                    $(this).toggleClass("YourOldClassName");
                }
            })
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this:
http://jsfiddle.net/uGudk/33/

Please consider using unique id for all form elements, and use unique input name also.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[name=last]").keydown(function () {
       if($(this).val().length > 0){
          $(this).attr("class", "class");
           //or change the submit button
           $("input[type=submit]").attr("class", "class");
           //or if you want to enable it if originally disbaled
           $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
       }
    });   
});
```